# What's the different between Parse Javascript and Parse Cloud-Code?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm confused between the two ,What is the different between Parse Javascript vs Parse Cloud-Code?

https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide

https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide

Answer (score 4):

Cloud code is javascript code that runs on the Parse servers and can contain business logic or code that you don't want exposed in client side code.

Parse Javascript runs in the browser, with nodejs and in mobile using cordova/phonegap.